# Delay Queue in C# using System.Threading.Timer

Tags: c#, timer

I have to implement a Delay Queue in C# as there is no standard implementation of delay queue present in the C#. I am looking to use `System.Threading.Timer` for implementing delayed enqueue of a node.

```
public class DelayQueue<T>
{
    private Queue queue<T> = new Queue<T>();

    public void Enqueue(Object object)
    {
        this.queue.Enqueue(object as T);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T node, TimeSpan dueTime)
    {
         new System.Threading.Timer(this.Enqueue, node, dueTime, -1);
    }

    .
    .
    .
}
```

This approach looks fine to me but since I am new to C#(from C background), I want someones opinion that whether it is the right way or are there any better and more effective methods of doing the same?

Comment: I think this is probably a better fit for codereview.stackexchage.com.

Comment: If it works, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: It is not fine, you have two major bugs.  You have to protect the queue with a lock since the timer callback runs on a threadpool thread.  And you have to keep a reference to the timer object to prevent it from getting garbage collected.  Both bugs are very hard to diagnose since they strike so infrequently.  The usage scenario is very strange, it might make more sense to delay the consumer.  Do favor BlockingQueue when you can.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that creating timers for each item is a good idea. Anyway, you only need to get first ready item when you dequeue item from queue, then you just can store time when item will be ready:

```
public class DelayQueue<T>
{
    private List<DelayQueueItem<T>> items = new List<DelayQueueItem<T>>();

    public void Enqueue(T item)
    {
        Enqueue(item, TimeSpan.Zero);
    }

    public void Enqueue(T item, TimeSpan delay)
    {
        items.Add(new DelayQueueItem<T>()
        {
            Value = item,
            ReadyTime = DateTime.Now.Add(delay)
        });
    }

    public T Dequeue()
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;
        var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ReadyTime <= now);
        if (item != null)
        {
            items.Remove(item);
            return item.Value;
        }

        return default(T);
    }

    private class DelayQueueItem<T>
    {
        public T Value { get; set; }
        public DateTime ReadyTime { get; set; }
    }
}
```

UPDATE (blocking queue with waiting timeout)

```
public T Dequeue()
{
    return Dequeue(TimeSpan.Zero);
}

public T Dequeue(TimeSpan timeout)
{
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;

    do
    {
        DateTime now = DateTime.Now;

        var item = items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ReadyTime <= now);
        if (item == null)
            continue;

        items.Remove(item);
        return item.Value;
    }
    while (DateTime.Now - startTime < timeout);

    return default(T);
}
```

Usage:

```
DelayQueue<string> queue = new DelayQueue<string>();
queue.Enqueue("world", new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1));
queue.Enqueue("hello");                        
queue.Enqueue(",");

TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 2);
Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue());
Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue(timeout));
Console.WriteLine(queue.Dequeue(timeout));
```

Comment: Is it possible to make `Dequeue` function as blocking? Actually, I was thinking of `Timer` so that I can have blocking delay queue by using the `BlockingQueue<T>` instance instead of the standard `Queue<T>`.

Comment: @RaviGupta sure, I've updated sample with blocking Dequeue methods

Comment: @RaviGupta also keep in mind, that this solution is not very accurate - if some item will get ready while you are searching for ready items in items collection, it will not be returned